# TI 84 Plus CE with Python not able to handle complex polar form in degrees.

Tags: complex-numbers, calculator

I am aware that the TI 84 calculators only allow the angle for complex polar form to be in radians. On my old TI 84 (I just got a new TI 84 Plus CE), I could work around this issue (no matter what mode I am in) by multiplying the angle in degrees by $\frac{\pi}{180}$. For instance, if I wanted to input this complex number:

$e^{45i}$

I would store the value of $\frac{\pi}{180}$ inside of `A`:

$e^{45Ai}$

And it would work and give the same answer no matter what mode I am in. It automatically assumed that I was giving the angle in radians, then evaluated it.

Now, with my new TI 84 Plus CE with Python, it won't let me evaluate that number at all if I am in degrees. It gives me this error:

```
Error: Domain

Value entered is not allowed in the function or command.
```

I need this to work in degrees so that I won't have to jump back and forth for when I am calling the `Polar` function to transform a complex rectangular number to complex polar.

Does anyone else having this problem, or know of a work around?

Comment: This is off-topic here, and [Where should I ask questions about using TI-84 calculators?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/324762/where-should-i-ask-questions-about-using-ti-84-calculators) doesn't help much, either.

Comment: I'll take this to stack overflow, but leave this here just in case. Thanks! @dxiv